# Multidimensional array with object and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have facing issue in accessing the index 1 in a array.
How can i access the `index 1`?

Tried to access like this.

```
$selection = $menu_selection->{1}->vl
```

but i it showing undefined offset error. can anyone help me.

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vl] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [op] => Array
                (
                    [0] => O
                    [1] => O
                )

        )

    [189] => Array
        (
            [vl] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You can access an array with `[index]` notation, so have you tried `$selection = $menu_selection[1]->vl`?

Comment: `$menu_selection[1]->vl[0]`

Comment: i have tried....error is undefined offset 1.

Comment: I think the index is not a array, it is an object inside a array...so how can i access it?

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 7.2 on you can do this (costly way):

```
((object) $menu_selection)->{1}->v1;
```

If way of accessing values doesn't matter it should be:

```
$menu_selection[1]->v1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a two errors.

`$selection = $menu_selection->{1}->vl`

The first error is accessing the first array position, you must do something like this `$selection = $menu_selection[1]`.
The second error is using `->`, this notation is used to access object properties and to call object functions.

To access index 1, you do something like this:

`$selection = $menu_selection[1]`

To access vl from array 1 try:

`$selection = $menu_selection[1]->vl`

As you can see in the var_dump, $menu_selection[1] is an object of type stdClass, that's why you need `->` to access the vl property.